# react native, @gorhom/bottom-sheet keyboardBehavior not working in android

Tags: android, react-native, bottom-sheet

```
"dependencies": {
        "@apollo/client": "^3.7.14",
        "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "4.4.7",
        "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
        "graphql": "^15.5.1",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-native": "^0.64.2",
        "react-native-camera": "^3.44.3",
        "react-native-flash-message": "^0.2.0",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
        "react-native-reanimated": "2.2.0",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
        "react-native-screens": "^3.4.0",
        "recoil": "^0.6.1",
        "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
        "@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0",
        "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
        "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
        "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
        "apollo-link-error": "^1.1.13",
        "react-apollo-network-status": "^5.2.1",
        "react-native-config": "^1.5.1",
        "react-native-rename": "^3.2.12"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.0",
        "@react-native-community/eslint-plugin": "^1.1.0",
        "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
        "eslint": "^7.30.0",
        "jest": "^27.0.6",
        "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
        "typescript": "4.8.4",
        "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
        "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
        "@types/react": "^17.0.2",
        "@types/react-native": "^0.64.2"
    },
    "resolutions": {
        "@types/react": "^17.0.2",
        "@types/react-native": "^0.64.2"
    },
```

my package.json

I'm using a bottom sheet, but even if I get a keyboard on Android, the bottom sheet won't go up
Of course, iOS works

When I get a keyboard, I want the bottom sheet to go up

I think it's a version problem, so I changed the bottom sheet from 4.5.5 to 4.5.7

this is my bottomSheet code

```
const defaultSnapPoint = ['35%', '90%'];
const snapPoint = useMemo(() => defaultSnapPoint, []);

    return (
        <>
            <CustomModal />
            {bottomSheet === 'FINDER' ? (
                <FindContainer isRecall={isRecall} />
            ) : (
                <ScanContainer isRecall={isRecall} />
            )}
            <BottomSheet
                snapPoints={snapPoint}
                keyboardBehavior="extend"
                android_keyboardInputMode="adjustPan" // i tried adjustResize
            >
                {isRecall ? <RecallButtonTab /> : <ButtonTab />}
                {getContainerComponentByTab()}
            </BottomSheet>
        </>
    );
```

and BottomSheetTextInput code

```
<AddDeviceContainer>
            <MainText>추가할 시리얼을 입력해주세요.</MainText>
            <VerticalSpacer />
            <SubText>다중 시리얼은 , 로 구분하여 입력해주세요.</SubText>
            <VerticalSpacer />
            <BottomSheetTextInput
                placeholder="시리얼을 입력해주세요. (예: 22800001, 22800002..."
                placeholderTextColor="gray"
                value={serialInput}
                onChangeText={handleChangeText}
                style={inputStyle}
                autoFocus
            />
            <VerticalSpacer />
            <ButtonRowContainer>
                <DeviceAddButton onPress={addDevice}>
                    <ButtonText>{serials.length}개 추가</ButtonText>
                </DeviceAddButton>
                <CancelButton onPress={changeBottomSheet}>
                    <ButtonText>취소</ButtonText>
                </CancelButton>
            </ButtonRowContainer>
        </AddDeviceContainer>
```

It works well in the iOS environment, but only on Android!!
please help me